# How to add backref citation page-number in the bibliography? natbib package and abbrvnat style

Tags: bibtex, natbib, back-referencing

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\hypersetup{citecolor=red}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=red, colorlinks=true}

\label{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\lhead{\emph{References}}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

Am using the third option on here [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/theses) (Masters/Doctoral Theses). I want to have citation page numbers next to the reference (bibliography item). I tried couple of options and couldn't compile.

Comment: Have you tried it with package `backref` or the option `backref` for `hyperref`?

Comment: Code please? I think I did and it didnt work

Comment: That was suggestion. To give a more useful solution, we need a compilable example to test.

Comment: I'm using the template as stated in my question

Comment: Please read about [minimal testing cases that save the time of supporters](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: I will only end up copying the "workable" template.. Hence, I have stated that in my original question..

Comment: @user70997: Please add the information as Johannes suggested

Answer (score 5):

As has been pointed out so many hours ago, the key is using package `backref`.

```
\documentclass{Thesis}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}%
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{backref}
\begin{document}
and inserts references such as this one \citep{Reference3}. The
\citep{Reference2, Reference1}) and multiple, sequential
\clearpage
\citep{Reference2, Reference1, Reference3}). This is done
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{Bibliography} 
\end{document}
```

---

Since the above mentioned Template is one of many worse template, not  only on this site, the `hyperref` approach does not work, since package `natbib` is loaded *after* package `hyperref` hurting the general rule of thumb that `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package.

The only way to come around this situation is changing the `Thesis` class, a thing that should never be done by unexperienced users, because that leads to thousands of versions of the same file claiming to be the same.